# How to made to work Codeception + facebook webdriver agent?

Tags: php, ios, facebook, appium

okay, i'm setup appium 1.6.3 server on my mac, webdriver agent inspector works great on real device. now i have this config in codeception yml file:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - \Appium\AppiumDriver:
            host: 0.0.0.0
            port: 4723
            dummyRemote: false
            resetAfterSuite: true
            resetAfterCest: false
            resetAfterTest: false
            resetAfterStep: false
            capabilities:
              app             : '/Users/kirill/Documents/iCanDeliver/Deliver.app'
              platformName    : 'ios'
              platformVersion : '10.3'
              deviceName      : 'iPhone (Kirill)'
              automationName  : 'XCUITest'
              udid: c57bcfcc08ee2485d02f30298dc98bef808a39a5
```

when I concept run any script appium server unlock the real device, deploy app, deploy webdriveragent, connect to webdriveragent, starting app OK,
but how to writing cases? maybe I made something wrong, there is no any info about codeception-webdriveragent.
Thanks!